# Code blocks between #if 0 and #endif must have paired double quotes?

Tags: c

```
int main(void)
{
    #if 0
    something"
    #endif
    return 0;
}
```

A simple program above generates a warning: `missing terminating " character` in gcc. This seems odd, because it means that the compiler allow the code blocks between `#if 0` and `endif` have invalid statement like `something` here, but not double quotes `"` that don't pair. The same happens in the use of `#ifdef` and `#ifndef`.

Real comments are fine here:

```
int main(void)
{
    /*
    something"
    */
    return 0;
}
```

Why? And the single quote `'` behave similarly, is there any other tokens that are treating specially?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I used an online gcc to test http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php

Comment: Couldn't reproduce this with clang (Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) or gcc (i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1)

Comment: clang doesn't throw anything. gcc trows, though. Same with clang++/g++.

Comment: gcc 4.6 and 4.1 reproduce that  warning

Comment: If you think about it, the preprocessor must parse the stuff in an inactive `#if` section because it has to deal with nested conditional compilations - the next `#endif` it comes across might not be the matching one.

Comment: Have seen this sort of problem before.   It typically arises when mistakenly using conditional compile directives to create comment blocks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the [comp.Lang.c FAQ, 11.19](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=ansi#ifdefsyntax):

> Under ANSI C, the text inside a "turned off" #if, #ifdef, or #ifndef must still consist of "valid preprocessing tokens." This means that the characters " and ' must each be paired just as in real C code, and the pairs mustn't cross line boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

Compilation needs to go through many cycles, before generating executable binary.

You are not in the compiler yet. Your pre-processor is flagging this error. This will not check for C language syntax, but missing quotes, braces and things like that are pre-processor errors.

After this pre-processor pass, Your code will go to the C Compiler which will detect the error you are expecting...

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor works at the token level, and a string literal is considered a single token.  The preprocessor is warning you that you have an invalid token.

According to the C99 standard, a preprocessing token is one of these things:

- header-name
- identiﬁer
- pp-number
- character-constant
- string-literal
- punctuator
- each non-white-space character that cannot be one of the
  above

The standard also says:

> If a ' or a " character matches the last category, the behavior is
>   undeﬁned.

Things like "statement" above are invalid to the C compiler, but it is a valid token, and the preprocessor eliminates this token before it gets to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the Kevin's answer, [Incompatibilities of GCC](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/ada/gnat/html/gcc_10.html#SEC176) says:

> GCC complains about unterminated character constants inside of preprocessing conditionals that fail. Some programs have English comments enclosed in conditionals that are guaranteed to fail; if these comments contain **apostrophes**, GCC will probably report an error. For example, this code would produce an error:
>
> ```
> #if 0
> You can't expect this to work.
> #endif
> ```
>
> The best solution to such a problem is to put the text into an actual C comment delimited by `/*...*/`.