# gcc parsing code which has been #if 0 out

Tags: c, gcc

This is the piece of code

```
#if 0
This is silly's comment
#endif
int main()
{
}
```

I get the error

```
apos.c:2:14: warning: missing terminating ' character [enabled by default]
 This is silly's comment
              ^
```

I can fix this by putting the comment inside /* */ or not using the apostrophe in the comment but what I'd like to know is how I can stop gcc from parsing stuff that has been #if 0'd out.

Comment: It's a GCC bug. Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24230708/2455888) in the dupe marked.

Comment: @haccks, no it is not a bug, it is a feature.

Comment: @JensGustedt; But it is mentioned there in *Incompatibilities* section.

Comment: @haccks It's not a bug. The standard requires that code inside conditional blocks must still consist of valid tokens.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves; http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/ada/gnat/html/gcc_10.html#SEC176. Read 11th point.